# How to use a placeholder for Angular Material 7 drag and drop?

Tags: angular, angular-material

I am using Angular Material 7's [Drag and Drop library](https://material.angular.io/cdk/drag-drop), and I am trying to figure out how to use the [cdkDragPlaceholder](https://material.angular.io/cdk/drag-drop/api#CdkDragPlaceholder).

> **CdkDragPlaceholder**
>
> Element that will be used as a template for the placeholder of a
>   *CdkDrag* when it is being dragged. The placeholder is displayed in
>   place of the element being dragged.
>
> Selector: ng-template[cdkDragPlaceholder]

I have tried the following code ([see Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dragndrop)):

```
 <div class="example-box" *ngFor="let movie of movies" cdkDrag>
    <div class="example-custom-placeholder" *cdkDragPlaceholder>asd</div>
    {{movie}}
  </div>
```

but there are no placeholders when dragging. If I wrap the above code inside a div with the `cdkDropList`-directive however I am able to see the placeholder. What can I do to make sure I use the placeholder correctly, only for an element with the `cdkDrag`-directive attached to it (not necesseraly using a `cdkDragList`).

Comment: where is the harm to simply wrap with `cdkDropList` and add `cdkDropListSortingDisabled` for preventing any UI distortions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems like the feature you're looking for may not be available yet.

I tested this too, and trying to use a `*cdkDragPlaceholder` element without creating a `cdkDropList` doesn't appear to appear to work. [The docs](https://material.angular.io/cdk/drag-drop/overview#customizing-the-drag-placeholder) don't make this distinction, but they also don't provide any examples of placeholders working outside of a list.

**You might keep an eye on [this GitHub](https://github.com/angular/components/issues/15034) issue**, as it seems to be asking for the feature you're trying to implement.

Good luck!