# How to add a placeholder template to an Angular Material CDK drag reference

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-cdk

I'm using the [DragDrop](https://v8.material.angular.io/cdk/drag-drop/api#DragDrop) service in materials CDK as I'm making dynamically created components draggable. The createDrag function returns a DragRef object which has a function `withPlaceholderTemplate`.

This function expects a parameter `template: DragHelperTemplate<any>`. The problem is DragHelperTemplate isn't exposed anywhere. Upon further investigating I found an interface in node_modules@angular\cdk\typings\drag-drop\drag-ref.d.ts which is as follows

```
interface DragHelperTemplate<T = any> {
    template: TemplateRef<T> | null;
    viewContainer: ViewContainerRef;
    context: T;
}
```

However this interface isn't exposed and even if it where I'm unsure how to create one. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use a placeholder for Angular Material 7 drag and drop?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54549461/how-to-use-a-placeholder-for-angular-material-7-drag-and-drop)

Comment: No, That isn't being implemented using the service. Thanks though!

Answer (score 1):

component.html:

```
<ng-template #placeholder>me placeholder</ng-template>
```

component.ts:

```
...
@ViewChild("placeholder", { read: TemplateRef }) placeholderRef: TemplateRef<any>;
...
constructor(
  private readonly dragDropService: DragDrop,
  private readonly viewContainerRef: ViewContainerRef,
) {}

...
const placeholder = {
  template: this.placeholderRef,
  context: null,
  viewContainer: this.viewContainerRef,
};

const dragRef = this.dragDropService.createDrag(...);
dragRef.withPlaceholderTemplate(placeholder);
```

Works for me

Comment: unfortunately in my case I could not use @ViewChild since it was being managed by a service

Answer (score 0):

I wasn't able to figure out how to get a placeholder working with the `DragHelperTemplate`. However for my case I found out I could just directly style `.cdk-drag-placeholder` class and have the placeholder look the way I wanted. Hopefully this helps someone.